# InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [15,3] vs. [100,3]

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have a dataset with more than 4000 images and 3 classes, and I'm reusing a code for capsule neural network with 10 classes but I modified it to 3 classes, when I'm running the model the following error occurs at the last point of the first epoch (44/45):

```
   Epoch 1/16
   44/45 [============================>.] - ETA: 28s - loss: 0.2304 - capsnet_loss: 0.2303 - decoder_loss: 0.2104 - capsnet_accuracy: 0.6598 - decoder_accuracy: 0.5781
    InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [15,3] vs. [100,3]
         [[node gradient_tape/margin_loss/mul/Mul (defined at <ipython-input-22-9d913bd0e1fd>:11) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_6157]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

Training code:

```
m = 100
epochs = 16
# Using EarlyStopping, end training when val_accuracy is not improved for 10 consecutive times
early_stopping = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_capsnet_accuracy',mode='max',
                                    patience=2,restore_best_weights=True)

# Using ReduceLROnPlateau, the learning rate is reduced by half when val_accuracy is not improved for 5 consecutive times
lr_scheduler = keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_capsnet_accuracy',mode='max',factor=0.5,patience=4)
train_model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001),loss=[margin_loss,'mse'],loss_weights = [1. ,0.0005],metrics=['accuracy'])
train_model.fit([x_train, y_train],[y_train,x_train], batch_size = m, epochs = epochs, validation_data = ([x_test, y_test],[y_test,x_test]),callbacks=[early_stopping,lr_scheduler])
```

The model is:

```
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(100, 28, 28, 1)]   0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)                 (100, 27, 27, 256)   1280        input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D)    (100, 27, 27, 256)   0           conv2d[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (100, 19, 19, 128)   2654336     max_pooling2d[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)               (100, 6, 6, 128)     1327232     conv2d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
reshape (Reshape)               (100, 576, 8)        0           conv2d_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda (Lambda)                 (100, 576, 8)        0           reshape[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
digitcaps (CapsuleLayer)        (100, 3, 16)         221184      lambda[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_2 (InputLayer)            [(None, 3)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
mask (Mask)                     (100, 48)            0           digitcaps[0][0]                  
                                                                 input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
capsnet (Length)                (100, 3)             0           digitcaps[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
decoder (Sequential)            (None, 28, 28, 1)    1354000     mask[0][0]                       
==================================================================================================
Total params: 5,558,032
Trainable params: 5,558,032
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Input layer,convulational layers and primary capsule

```
img_shape=(28,28,1)
inp=L.Input(img_shape,100)
# Adding the first conv1 layer
conv1=L.Conv2D(filters=256,kernel_size=(2,2),activation='relu',padding='valid')(inp)
# Adding Maxpooling layer
maxpool1=L.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1,1))(conv1)
# Adding second convulational layer
conv2=L.Conv2D(filters=128,kernel_size=(9,9),activation='relu',padding='valid')(maxpool1)
# Adding primary cap layer
conv2=L.Conv2D(filters=8*16,kernel_size=(9,9),strides=2,padding='valid',activation=None)(conv2)
# Adding the squash activation
reshape2=L.Reshape([-1,8])(conv2)
squashed_output=L.Lambda(squash)(reshape2)
```

code [source](https://www.kaggle.com/accountstatus/capsule-network)

x_train.shape --> (4415, 28, 28, 1)

y_train.shape --> (4415, 3)

x_test.shape --> (1104, 28, 28, 1)

y_test.shape --> (1104, 3)

My code [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10L9pbC4alQgnirMfzHjb3h9uv6WbtKMS/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try make the X set so that the batch size perfectly fits the data i think the batch size remainder is 15 after fitting to all the data

For eg : make it a multiple of 100